# How to pass the data from background process to another activity

Tags: android, background, bluetooth, real-time

I could get the data appear saved in variable sbprint on screen from main activity. The varible sbprint i get from background activity that buffer bluetooth data. I want to log the data appear on screen to another class.
The problem is i can't use serializable since the data always stream from my bluetooth module in real-time mode. The code based on [here](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php)

I use handler to update my UI from data buffered 
NOTE: I obtain shared preference inside handler (this is inside MainActivity.java)

```
h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView

                        SharedPreferences logPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = logPreferences.edit();
                        String textLog = txtArduino.getText().toString();
                        editor.putString("log", textLog);
                        editor.commit();

                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
                }
            };
        };
```

the h Handler get the message object from ConnectedThread class based on bluetooth documentation in this command,

```
h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
```

My question is, how do I pass the variable sbprint into my new screen in another class using handler just like above.

here's how i received data from data passed in another. I pass the data in variable buffer by getting from shared preferences as suggested

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datalog);

        tvDatalog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDatalog);

        SharedPreferences logPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String text = logPreferences.getString("log", "null");
        tvDatalog.setText(text+"\r\n");
    }
```

NOTE: 
I got the data from my MainActivity but seems like my asynctask that works inside my MainActivity stopped as the screen change to another class. How do i make my background activity also works on both class. I mean whenever i am changing my screen on one to another  the background activity always working.

Comment: I'm not sure it works for you but you can store your data in shared preferences and retrieve it anywhere in your application. Don't use serialisable since it makes your app too slow.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that. Any recommended link about shared preferences?

Comment: Best reference is Android documentations. Please refer to following link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: so is this shared preferences compatible for handling the updated variable over time? which is more efficient between shared preference and static variable?

Comment: every time you get updated data, you need to store it as String (or array of strings based on your need) and retrieve it in your other activities. Static variable is better choice if one class is handling your data. Shared preferences is good choice if different classes/activities needs to have access to data.

Comment: hei @Hesam i updated the code using shared preferences as you suggested. But seems like my background activity from my main class stop working by the time i change my screen. How do i make my background activity that provide variable on shared preferences also working when the screen changes? thx

Comment: I guess your problem is something else. Based on what you said in last paragraph, "...my asynctask that works inside my MainActivity stopped as the screen change to another class". If you mean you have two activities, from fist activity you are running AsyncTask then by calling Second activity, first activity goes to onStop() and even onDestroy(). That's why your AsyncTask stops. Instead of AsyncTask use Android Services and run it from your first activity. you can search about it. Then it's alive as long as your application is alive.

Comment: thank you @Hesam for your thought, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you might want to use an interface. You can define an interface in the `Activity` that contains the `Handler`. Then you can implement the interface in the desired `Class`.

Comment: i'm sorry i just heard the interface thing. Is this different way of passing data just like intent? why would i want to use interface? thanks

Comment: one of the uses for an interface is to create a callback (i.e. a listener like `onClickListener()`) which is what you might want in this case. Look at the link for a more detailed explanation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html